# Significance arithmetic in calc

Tags: calc

I would like to perform [significance arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significance_arithmetic) in `calc-mode`. For example, I want `5000` to have one significant figure, and `5.0e3` to have two significant figures. Calculations should preserve significant figures according to the rules of significance arithmetic. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, this isn't something Calc can do. I know, however Sage: http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/rings_numerical/sage/rings/real_mpfi.html can do something similar.

Comment: The nearest you can get with calc is to use [error forms](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Error-Forms.html) for propagation of uncertainty, or [interval forms](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Interval-Forms.html) for hard interval propagation. The final error or interval will determine the significant digits in your result.